# Django 1.7: Passing around unsaved instances throws "unhashable" exception

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-1.7

I'm migrating over to Django 1.7 currently. I have some signals that pass an unsaved model instance, which now throws `TypeError: Model instances without primary key value are unhashable`.

I'm wondering how does Django `pre_save` signal pass around the instance then? I'm looking around the docs and even found the commit which implemented this in 1.7 (https://github.com/django/django/commit/6af05e7a0f0e4604d6a67899acaa99d73ec0dfaa), and I just have no idea how it even works.

Could someone explain to me either how pre_save gets around this or how I can get around this limitation myself? Thanks.

Example code below:

```
from django.dispatch import Signal

send_text = Signal()
unsaved_model = SomeModel()  # note that neither `create` or `.save()` are being called
send_text.send(sender=unsaved_model)  # error gets thrown when this gets called
```

Traceback:

```
  File "/home/ubuntu/fangsterr-app/notifications/models.py", line 43, in send
    send_text.send(sender=self)
  File "/home/ubuntu/virtualenvs/venv-2.7.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 194, in send
    if not self.receivers or self.sender_receivers_cache.get(sender) is NO_RECEIVERS:
  File "/home/ubuntu/virtualenvs/venv-2.7.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 484, in __hash__
    raise TypeError("Model instances without primary key value are unhashable")
TypeError: Model instances without primary key value are unhashable
```

Comment: I'm not aware of any requirement that arguments to signals be hashable. Can you show the actual code that is generating the error, along with the complete traceback?

Comment: just added an example

Comment: Please provide the full traceback.

Comment: added full traceback as well

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like Django stores the `sender` in a cache that it uses for lookup during signal dispatch. That requires the `sender` to be hashable, which doesn't work on a model instance without a `pk`.

The reason this doesn't affect `pre_save` et al. is that, by convention, the `sender` is the model *class*, not the model *instance*. The `instance` is passed in its own argument. See [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#pre-save).

The solution is easy—use the class as the `sender`, and pass the instance as an argument.

(If this worked before it was just happenstance. The [bug](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/18864) that was fixed caused all unsaved model instances to evaluate as equal.)

Comment: yah after looking at the traceback again, i came to the same conclusion. thanks for posting